# sockets no conecta localhost [Winerror 10061]

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, socket, virtualbox

Tengo un pequeño problema con un script en sockets.

Verán el día de ayer al probar el código del cliente y el servidor funcionaba perfectamente con esta configuración:

**Servidor**

```
servidor= socket.socket()
conexion = ("Pc-1",900)
servidor.bind(conexion)
servidor.listen(1)
```

**Cliente**

```
conexion = ("Pc-1",900)
cliente = socket.socket()
```

Todo funcionaba perfectamente, pero por la noche utilicé este código pero ahora dentro de una maquina virtual en VirtualBox y funcionaba de igual manera.

Pero el día de hoy al probarlo de nuevo en 2 maquinas diferentes pero en la misma red no funciono.

Tuve que indicar manualmente la dirección ip del equipo servidor.

Ya que si lo trato de hacer mediante una variable el cliente no encuentra al servidor.

Ejemplo que no funciona:

**Servidor**

```
ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) #Variable que almacena el valor de la ip del equipo que es el seridor
servidor = socket.socket()
conexion = (ip,900) #Indico la variable ip como la direccion ip de el servidor
servidor.bind(conexion)
servidor.listen(1)
```

**Cliente**

```
conexion = ("192.168.8.1",900)
cliente = socket.socket()
cliente.connect(conexion)
```

Configuración que funciono al final:

**Servidor**

```
servidor = socket.socket()
conexion = (192.168.8.1,900) #Indico manualmente el numero de ip
servidor.bind(conexion)
servidor.listen(1)
```

**Cliente**

```
conexion = ("192.168.8.1",900)
cliente = socket.socket()
cliente.connect(conexion)
```

Como pueden ver debo de indicar manualmente la dirección ip sin embargo lo que busco es que la variable almacene ese valor y se lo pase a la función conexión para evitar ponerlo manualmente

ESTE ES EL ERROR QUE ARROJA EL CLIENTE AL TRATAR DE CONECTARSE

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En lugar de poner la IP del servidor "a mano", o tratar de obtenerla mediante `gethostname()`, que puede funcionar o no según como esté confgurado la resolución de nombres, una solución más general es que uses `servidor.bind(("", 900)`. Es decir, donde iría la IP pones una cadena vacía. Eso equivale a poner la ip `0.0.0.0`, que representa "todas las interfaces de red de este ordenador", y se adapta por tanto a la IP que tengas (y si tienes varios interfaces de red, escucharía por todos ellos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como se menciona el pregunta el problema fue **VirtualBox** mas en concreto el **Adaptador de red**.

Como se instala la maquina virtual la pc detecto como Adaptador de red predeterminado el adaptador de virtual box.

Esto lo podemos observar al ejecutar el comando `ipconfig` en la cmd

**Resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La dirección ip que tomaba el equipo era en este caso `192.168.56.1`

**Solución**

La solución desactivar el adaptador de red de VirtualBox

```
Panel de Control > Redes e Internet > Conexiones de Red
```

Desactivar **VirtualBox Host-Only Network**

Ejecutando de nuevo `ipconfig`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora el adaptador fue deshabilitado y la dirección ip del equipo ahora es la que le corresponde en este caso `192.168.8.4`

Y el error ConnectionRefusedError:[WinError 10061] desaparece y el cliente se conecta correctamente al servidor